# how to generate onclick listener for dynamically generated dynamic number of textviews in Androiod?

Tags: android

I have table 'notes' which has N notes. For every note, I want to print the value of 'title' column in separate textview which i create dynamically. So, for N notes, I will have N textviews.
Now, Whenever the user clicks on any textView, I want to display all other data of that row which has the clicked title.

### **The Problem:** When I use onClickListener to these dynamically created textviews, and When user clicks on any textview, It always generates the data of the last row(or of the last dyanmically created textview)

```
public void dataview(){
    //onView is a userdefined function which simply executes a select query 
    Cursor res=db.onView();
    len=res.getCount();

    //below code is, If no notes stored in the table.
    if(res.getCount()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this,"No Notes.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //parsing the select query result using the Cursor res
    while(res.moveToNext()) {
        relative = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_view);
        relative.addView(createNewTextView(res.getString(1).toString()));
    }
}

public TextView createNewTextView(String text){
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.setMargins(0,10,0,0);

    //creating TextView and assigning properties here
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(text);
    index++;
    textView.setTextSize(18);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0099cc"));

    // onClick Action here
    final String title=textView.getText().toString();
    textView.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Cursor res1=db.onView();
                            while(res1.moveToNext()){
                                if(res1.getString(1).equals(title));
                                {
                                    final String text1=res1.getString(0);
                                    Intent i=new Intent("com.example.dell.todolister.ViewNoteActivity");
                                    i.putExtra("TextBox1",text1);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a listview or recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give id to text view.

initialize global variable like int i = 1;

then in createNewTextView,  textView.setId(i)

at the end before you return a view increment i = i + 1;

so for next textView you will have different id for text view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use id to identify textview to display text,use this -->  `v.getid()` inside `onclick(View v)`

Answer (score 0):

I spent 24 hours to find the solution to this problem believing the problem to be related to some listener-specific-logic.

But The problem was the bloody Semicoln ';' on this line that caused all the problems

```
if(res1.getString(1).equals(title)); // Here :'(
{
    final String text1=res1.getString(0);
    Intent i=new Intent("com.example.dell.todolister.ViewNoteActivity");
    i.putExtra("TextBox1",text1);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
}
```